# OCI PDO no ejecuta el query en PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Me surgió este problema en mi proyecto final de la universidad y es una página web con PHP orientado a objetos, y gestor de base de datos ORACLE, todo iba bien con la conexión hasta que al momento de ejecutar un procedimiento en el PHP este no realiza nada.

Les dejare una parte de como tengo estructurado el proyecto, (estoy haciendo el modulo de usuario)

Esta es mi clase Conexion

```
    <?php
    class Connection
    {
      public $connection;

      public function __CONSTRUCT()
     {
       try{
         $this->connection = new PDO('oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/orcl',"username", "userpassword");
         $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       }catch(PDOException $e){
          die($e->getMessage());
       }
     }

   public function __getConnection()
   {
       return $this->connection;
   }
 }
```

Esta es mi clase Usuario

```
     <?php
     class Usuario
     {
       public $IdUsuario;
       public $Email;
       public $Clave;
       public $Rol;
       public $Estado;
       public $NombreUsuario;
       public $Foto;
       public $CodigoActivacion;
       public $Sexo;
       public $Tstamp;

    public function __GET($k)
    {
      return $this->$k;
    }

    public function __SET($k, $v)
    {
      $this->$k = $v;
    }
  }
```

esta es mi clase Modelo Usuario

```
  <?php
  /**
   *
   */
   require_once _dependencia_.'Objects/Usuario.php';
   require_once _dependencia_.'Connection/Connection.php';
   require_once _dependencia_.'Model/SesionModel.php';
   require_once _dependencia_.'Objects/Sesion.php';
   class UsuarioModel
  {
    private $connection;
    public function __construct()
    {
      try {
         $c = new Connection();
         $this->connection = $c->__getConnection();
      } catch (Exception $e) {
         die($e->getMessage());
     }
   }

    public function save($Usuario)
    {
      try {
          $sql = 'INSERT INTO Usuario (NombreUsuario, Email, Clave, Rol, Estado, Foto, CodigoActivacion,Sexo)
           VALUES (?, ? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?,?)';

        return $this->connection->prepare($sql)
         ->execute(
         array(
            $Usuario->__GET('NombreUsuario'),
            $Usuario->__GET('Email'),
            $Usuario->__GET('Clave'),
            $Usuario->__GET('Rol'),
            $Usuario->__GET('Estado'),
            $Usuario->__GET('Foto'),
            $Usuario->__GET('CodigoActivacion'),
            $Usuario->__GET('Sexo'),
            )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());

        return false;
    }
}
```

y esta es mi clase Constante

```
   <?php
     define("_ROOT_","http://localhost/SistemaBayerWeb/");
     define("_dependencia_","C:/xampp/htdocs/SistemaBayerWeb/");
   ?>
```

Comment: Por favor, sé más específico: ¿qué es lo que intentas realizar?¿cuál es el resultado esperado?¿qué resultado obtienes?¿recibes algún mensaje de error?

Comment: El resultado que deseo es que se inserten los valores en la BD, pero al momento de realizar el query este no hace nada. Lo que deseo es guardar los datos del Usuario.